# RDP - Enter password after lock timout

Tags: remote-desktop

I store my 25 character random generated passwords in a password manager (Lastpass).  When initiating a connection to a server over RDP I can copy and paste my password into the RDP connection window.

However, when the server locks after 15 minutes of inactivity, I'm unable to paste the password from the clipboard into the RDP window. I have the clipboard shared as a device in the RDP connection settings.

Is there a way to paste passwords into the locked RDP screen?

Comment: Those are two different dialogs. The first (NLA) allows paste. A straight up CTRL-ALT-DELETE? No, you will need to enter credentials.

Comment: A password manager with "auto type" might work.

Answer (score 1):

X-out the connection - the session will become disconnected but stay alive. Now re-establish it and you may use the clipboard again.